# How to create a login using google in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I just recently building an plugin in which I need to integrate Google Login. I searched and found `chrome.identity` to authenticate user using google account but that does not work well.

So I came across a solution by using this code below

```
    var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
    var clientId = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.client_id);
    var scopes = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.scopes.join(' '));
    var redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto');

    var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth' + 
              '?client_id=' + clientId + 
              '&response_type=code' + 
              '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri + 
              '&scope=' + scopes;

    var RESULT_PREFIX = ['Success', 'Denied', 'Error'];
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'about:blank'}, function(authenticationTab) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function googleAuthorizationHook(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
            if (tabId === authenticationTab.id) {
                
                var titleParts = tab.title.split(' ', 2);
                
                var result = titleParts[0];
                if (titleParts.length == 2 && RESULT_PREFIX.indexOf(result) >= 0) {
                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(googleAuthorizationHook);
                    chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);

                    var response = titleParts[1];
                    switch (result) {
                        case 'Success':
                            // Example: id_token=<YOUR_BELOVED_ID_TOKEN>&authuser=0&hd=<SOME.DOMAIN.PL>&session_state=<SESSION_SATE>&prompt=<PROMPT>
                            console.log("suc:"+response);
                        break;
                        case 'Denied':
                            // Example: error_subtype=access_denied&error=immediate_failed
                            console.log("denied:"+response);
                        break;
                        case 'Error':
                            // Example: 400 (OAuth2 Error)!!1
                            console.log("error:"+response);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        chrome.tabs.update(authenticationTab.id, {'url': url});
    });
```

In which if I remove `v2` from the url variable then it always gives error in the turn with `id_token` but if I add `v2` then its success and return code.

So now I read google documentation which said that now create a post request using `client_id and client_secret` but I chrome app create credential on google console which does not have `client_secret`

Now what should I do ? Is there anything that I missed or do wrong here and I also came across one of the chrome extension `Screencastify` use google login.

Can anyone explain how they do it ?

Answer (score 13):

There's an official [OAuth tutorial here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) for Chrome extensions/apps which you can refer to.

There's another [blog tutorial](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) here:

**Step 1: Copy library**

You will need to copy the oauth2 library into your chrome extension root into a directory called oauth2.

**Step 2: Inject content script**

Then you need to modify your manifest.json file to include a content script at the redirect URL used by the Google adapter. The "matches" redirect URI can be looked up in the table above:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.google.com/robots.txt*"],
    "js": ["oauth2/oauth2_inject.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],
```

**Step 3: Allow access token URL**

Also, you will need to add a permission to Google's access token granting URL, since the library will do an XHR against it. The access token URI can be looked up in the table above as well.

```
"permissions": [
  "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
]
```

**Step 4: Include the OAuth 2.0 library**

Next, in your extension's code, you should include the OAuth 2.0 library:

```
<script src="/oauth2/oauth2.js"></script>
```

**Step 5: Configure the OAuth 2.0 endpoint**

And configure your OAuth 2 connection by providing clientId, clientSecret and apiScopes from the registration page. The authorize() method may create a new popup window for the user to grant your extension access to the OAuth2 endpoint.

```
var googleAuth = new OAuth2('google', {
  client_id: '17755888930840',
  client_secret: 'b4a5741bd3d6de6ac591c7b0e279c9f',
  api_scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks'
});

googleAuth.authorize(function() {
  // Ready for action
});
```

**Step 6: Use the access token**

Now that your user has an access token via auth.getAccessToken(), you can request protected data by adding the accessToken as a request header

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + myAuth.getAccessToken())
```

or by passing it as part of the URL (depending on the server implementation):

```
myUrl + '?oauth_token=' + myAuth.getAccessToken();
```

Note: if you have multiple OAuth 2.0 endpoints that you would like to authorize with, you can do that too! Just inject content scripts and add permissions for all of the providers you would like to authorize with.

And here's the actual [github sample](https://github.com/borismus/oauth2-extensions/tree/master/samples) using those concepts.